# request django API using https doesn't work

Tags: python, django, docker

When I want to request an API using https it doesn't work and I don't know why..

Example :

```
`http://myIp:8888/getValue` --> it works
`https://myIp:8888/getValue` --> it doesn't work
```

There is my dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.7-buster
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

ENV PORT=8888

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        tzdata \
        python3-setuptools \
        python3-pip \
        python3-dev \
        python3-venv \
        git \
        && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

EXPOSE 8888

CMD gunicorn Documents_management_back.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

And my docker-compose

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Someone understand why I can't request using https ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please show your Django settings file.